# Error trying to get AdapterView.OnItemClickListener to work

Tags: java, android

Im trying to set up AdapterView.OnItemClickListener to work but it keeps bringing up an error and I cant seem to find an answer that works.

```
mListView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(RemindersActivity.this, "clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

[Error message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGEhN.png)
Hope someone can help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to set the `OnItemClickListener` as the `OnClickListener`.

You should have:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
...
```

[setOnItemClickListener documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))